# Error in Admin Category Page for Some Categories

Tags: magento2.3, admin, catalog, magento2.3.3

For some categories, instead of load category information, error is shown. This appears randomly for some categories.

Have tried reindex, updating file permission for `pub/` directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

V2.3.3

Comment: Looks like your Magento core file is modified, which version of Magento you are using?

Comment: 2.3.3. I am sure core file is not modified.

Comment: A possible issue is category image was not saved or Magento cannot build a path to the category image (it was a Magento bug). I cannot help you without investigating your problem.

Comment: How this can be resolved @PetroChaikivskyi. Number of categories showing same error. Cannot edit category info. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The simplest way is to disable errors output in PHP, in this case, the page should work. Edit `app/bootstrap.php` to disable errors. The proper way is to define why the PHP variable contains bad data and fix it, I cannot help you fix your issues here.